# how to display custom rectangle Alert dialog in android

Tags: android, kotlin

```
<RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@drawable/dialog_bg"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/nameText"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/profilePic"
                    android:ems="10"
                    android:fontFamily="sans-serif-medium"
                    android:letterSpacing="-0.03"
                    android:paddingRight="@dimen/margin_20dp"
                    android:text="Ajay Kulkarni"
                    android:textColor="#3e4360"
                    android:textSize="16sp"
                    android:textStyle="normal" />
                        <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/designation"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/nameText"
                    android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
                    android:gravity="end"
                    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/profilePic"

                    android:letterSpacing="-0.03"
                    android:paddingRight="@dimen/margin_20dp"
                    android:text=""
                    android:textSize="12sp"
                    android:textStyle="normal" />

                <com.kdcos.contsync.utilities.RoundedImageView
                    android:id="@+id/profilePic"
                    android:layout_width="32dp"
                    android:layout_height="32dp"
                    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                    android:background="@drawable/ic_my_profile" />

            </RelativeLayout>


        </RelativeLayout>
```

function for Alert Dialog:

```
 fun showChangeLangDialog(item: ReceivedCardModel) {
        val dialogBuilder = AlertDialog.Builder(this)
        val dialogBinding: DialogAttendeesDetailBinding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(LayoutInflater.from(this), R.layout.dialog_attendees_detail, null, false)
        dialogBuilder.setView(dialogBinding.root)
        val b = dialogBuilder.create()}
```

my current screen is coming like square dialog while my my expected screen is like rectangle in land scape mode  i tried to give padding from top and right but not able to get rectangle dialog. it please suggest me how i will do this Thanks. my expected screen like this :
[image]

Comment: Place layout xml in layout and layout_land folders, then automatically it will adjust as per orientation

Comment: i alredy place @Pinki